# Perl iterate through a file to find and save lines separately accordingly to different given patterns

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, readfile

I need to iterate through a log file (around 2MB) line by line, compare each with 5 different patterns and save those that give a match in separate arrays according to the pattern they match with. The patterns are presented in the file like the following:

```
(text)
pattern1
pattern2
(m lines of text)
pattern3
(2 lines of text)
pattern1
pattern2
(x lines of text)
pattern3
(this continues ~50-100 times where number of lines between pattern2 and pattern3 vary)
...
pattern3
(5 lines of text)
pattern4
(2 lines of text)
pattern5
(text)
```

I am aware that a lot of similar questions have been asked and answered, however, I do not really understand the code in those answers. What I plan to do is:

1. Read each line, check for `pattern1` and `pattern2` until the first match using 2 `if` statements then exit the loop immediately.
2. Start another `while (my $line = <FILE>)` loop, check only for `pattern3`, if match found, save the line with `pattern3` and the followings `pattern1` and `pattern2` lines (which are the 3rd and 4th lines from `pattern3`)

Here are my questions:

a. When I exit a `while (<FILE>)` loop before it reaches the end and start another `while ($line = <FILE>)` loop immediately after that, does the 2nd loop start reading from the top again or continue from where it stopped?

b. Can anyone be kind enough to give a sample commented implementation for step 2?

c. How can I make use of the search for `pattern3` to get the line with `pattern4` and `pattern5`since the match for `pattern4` and `pattern5` is a fixed distance away from the last match of `pattern3`.

d. Will my plan be more efficient than simply using `if-else` statements that checks for all 5 patterns for every line (which, eg if there are 30 `pattern1`'s, the total number of comparisons is 6*30 + 4 + 5 + 5*number of lines with no match)?

e. Any better/more efficient way to solve my problem? The percentage of having a line matched to any pattern is around 1%.

I would really appreciate any answer/suggestion/alternative provided. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need two separate whiles. It seems unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. You can just check for it in a single loop. Just do not make it a elsif, but another if and do not exit the loop inside the first branch.

Comment: I intend to have a second `while` so that after the first 2 matches I do not need to check for `pattern1` and `pattern2` again.

Comment: btw shouldn't `elsif` be better, since once you have a match you can proceed to check the next line immediately?

Comment: Yes, you can do a `while (my $line = <FILE>) { while (my $line = <FILE>) { ...} ...}` Scope is honored for the $line, and `<FILE>` position is only increased on the handle. The handle would have to be reset to start from the beginning of file. And you should use <$file> variable instead of <FILE>.

Comment: I appreciate your attempts to simplify your log file data, but it would be more help to see the real data together with a full description of the result that you require

Comment: Instead of using a second while loop, which I think would be confusing, just keep the patterns you're checking for saved somehow, perhaps in a list or something.  You can either modify the pattern array when you want to change what you're searching for or track the indexes of the array that you should be checking for and update those when certain criteria are met...  Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the 5 patterns in advance, that would be easy. Do you? Or are they part of the input file and unpredictable?

Assuming you know them in advance:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $current_pattern = 'else';
my $pattern_arrays = {
    'pattern1' => [],
    'pattern2' => [],
    'pattern3' => [],
    'pattern4' => [],
    'pattern5' => [],
    'else'     => [],
};

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp($line); # remove trailing '\n' from $line

    # See if we just read one of our 5 patterns. Remember that
    # as the $current_pattern, and proceed to the next line.
    if ( $line =~ /^(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5)$/ ) {
        $current_pattern = $line;
        next; # jump back to "while...", i.e. proceed to next line
    }

    # If we get here, we have some $current_pattern, which is one
    # of "pattern1" ... "pattern5" or "else". The $current_pattern
    # is only "else" at the beginning, when we haven't found a
    # pattern yet (i.e. only the first line in your case).
    # Push the $line to the array that belongs to the $current_pattern.
    push @{$pattern_arrays->{$current_pattern}}, $line;
}

# Pretty-print the arrays.
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1; # Sort Data::Dumper output by keys
print Data::Dumper->Dump( [$pattern_arrays], ['pattern_arrays'] );

__DATA__
(text)
pattern1
pattern2
(m lines of text)
pattern3
(2 lines of text)
pattern1
pattern2
(x lines of text)
pattern3
(this continues ~50-100 times where number of lines between pattern2 and pattern3 vary)
...
pattern3
(5 lines of text)
pattern4
(2 lines of text)
pattern5
(text)
```

Yields:

```
$pattern_arrays = {
                    'else' => [
                                '(text)'
                              ],
                    'pattern1' => [],
                    'pattern2' => [
                                    '(m lines of text)',
                                    '(x lines of text)'
                                  ],
                    'pattern3' => [
                                    '(2 lines of text)',
                                    '(this continues ~50-100 times where number of lines between pattern2 and pattern3 vary)',
                                    '...',
                                    '(5 lines of text)'
                                  ],
                    'pattern4' => [
                                    '(2 lines of text)'
                                  ],
                    'pattern5' => [
                                    '(text)',
                                    ''
                                  ]
                  };
```

Actually, I'm not really sure if that is what you asked for.
Of course, instead of `<DATA>` you would use some other `<FILE>`.

Comment: This is not exactly what I am looking for. I have found a solution to my problem which is storing my data in an array and it becomes super simple to get any line I need. However, the code you provided to separate the data would still be very useful for future reference. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Btw I have seen `Data::Dumper` being used quite frequently in Perl code, do you mind explaining what is the use of it? Thanks!

Comment: [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) is a module to serialize a Perl data structures, i.e. to convert them into a string, no matter how complicated the structure is (hashes of hashes, arrays, you name it). The resulting string can be printed or saved to disk and later be reloaded and `eval`'ed back into the original data structure. It's a bit similar to JSON. _And,_ and that's what most people use it for, it's perfect for debugging as you can print out your structures to see what's actually in them.